# Finding the depth of a BST base on the key specified

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
def depth(self, key):
    temp = self.get(key)
    current = self.root
    depthCount = 0
    if temp is None: 
        return None
    if self.root.key is key:  
       return 0
    if current.key < key and (temp.right is not None): 
        current = current.right
        depthCount += 1
        depthCount = self.depth(temp.right.key)
    if current.key > key and (temp.left is not None):
        current = current.left  # key < Root Key
        depthCount += 1
        depthCount = self.depth(temp.left.key)
    return depthCount
```

Hi I'm trying to find the depth based on the code I gave, but whenever I tried running it, it just gave me the height of the Node, not the Depth.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these lines of code:

```
depthCount += 1
depthCount = self.depth(temp.right.key)
```

For a minute, let's set aside the fact that this code is recursive. Imagine I had written this code:

```
depthCount += 1
depthCount = myMagicFunction()
```

This code looks a little odd - the first line essentially has no effect because `depthCount` is being overwritten in the next line.

If your goal was to set `depthCount` to one plus whatever you get by calling the recursive function, you could do so by writing code like this:

```
depthCount = 1 + self.depth(temp.right.key)
```

Hope this helps!